# How to build scss/sass using sublime editor. is it possible to use(Sublime) for SCSS/SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried much time to use sublime editor but I have no idea how to use sublime editor for building scss/sass file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file with .scss extension in your project as start writing SASS styles. Add the file/ import the file in your desired location/component for integrating it with the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin for Sublime Text 2/3 providing four build systems for Sass/SCSS files [SASS Build](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SASS%20Build).
I hope it would help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply.but how to install sass/scss plugin in the sublime editor.

Comment: Please see the link attached in my answer.